# Changing page elements with JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, dom

Greetings fellow Stackoverflowers. I am trying to have text, images, and colors change with a single click of a button using JavaScript. Is there any efficient way to do this? Here is [My example Website](https://preview.c9users.io/th3h4ack3r/webdevproj/project%20-%20Copy.html?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io). I am trying to have the Edward Snowden's image, description, and  list change with a single button then revert to the original when clicked again! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know how to react to mouse clicks, and modify elements? You need to be more specific about what you're asking, as this is a very broad question.

Comment: There are many tutorials on using Javascript in web pages. SO is not a substitute for learning the craft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually rather simple to do this. Here is an example of what to do and how:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="image" src="image1.gif">
<p id="text">Old text</p>
<button onclick="change()">Click Me</button>

<script>
function change() {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "image2.jpg";
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "new text";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You declare elements with IDs and make a button with an onclick event. When the button is clicked, it will run the `change()` function, which will change `image`'s `src` to `image2.jpg` and `text`'s text to `new text`.

If you want it to change back, you could try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="image" src="image1.gif">
<p id="text">Old text</p>
<button onclick="change()">Click Me</button>

<script>
var element1;
var element2;

function change() {

    element1 = document.getElementById("image")
    element2 = document.getElementById("text")

    if ( element1.src == "image2.jpg" ) {
        element1.src = "image1.gif"
        element2.innerHTML = "Old text"
    } else {
        element1.src = "image2.jpg"
        element2.innerHTML = "new text"
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! However, how do I make it when the button is clicked again it returns to the original content?

Answer (score 0):

```
This method is for Jquery.

$(document).on('click', '.btn-color1', function(){
        $(this).addClass('btn-color2');
        $('.container').addClass('changecolor2');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.btn-color2', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('btn-color1');
        $('.container').removeClass('changecolor2');
        $('.container').addClass('changecolor3');
    });

<style>
        .btn-color1{
            color: #fff;
            background-color: red;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .btn-color2{
            color: #fff;
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .changecolor2{
            background-color: blue;
        }

</style>
```